# View binding with EpoxyModelWithHolder

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewbinding, epoxy, epoxy-modelview

I am using `EpoxyModelWithHolder` with multiple layouts in a single Epoxy model class. How can I do ViewBinding? Currently, I am using `Kotlin-android-extensions`. Below is my code

```
@EpoxyModelClass
abstract class ItemSampleEpoxyModel : EpoxyModelWithHolder() {

@EpoxyAttribute
var itemSampleShelf: ComponentFactoryLanderPagesHeroShelf.ComponentLanderPageHeroShelf.ItemLanderPageHeroShelf? =
    null

override fun getDefaultLayout() =
    when {
        itemSampleShelf?.heroStyle == "Project" -> {
            R.layout.item_project_sample
        }
        itemSampleShelf?.shelfItemType == "Course" -> {
            R.layout.item_course_sample
        }
        else -> {
            R.layout.item_sample
        }
    }

override fun bind(itemHolder: ItemSampleEpoxyHolder) {
    itemHolder.titleView.text = itemSampleShelf?.title
} }



class ItemSampleEpoxyHolder : EpoxyHolder() {


lateinit var titleView: AppCompatTextView

override fun bindView(itemView: View) {
    titleView = itemView.tv_title
}}
```

Comment: is `viewBinding` enabled in your project? I use data binding with Epoxy. We need to add thsi dependency `implementation "com.airbnb.android:epoxy-databinding:$epoxyVersion"`  in order to use data binding with epoxy.

Comment: I have added data binding, But how can I bind the layout to EpoxyModel

Comment: In my case the Binding for the layout is generated. so you can use LayoutBinding.inflate().. by the way I always use data binding so never tried to inflate layout.    Suppose your layout file is epoxy_sample_layout.xml and the `layoutPrefix=epoxy` then the DataBindingModel name will be `sampleLayout`

Comment: So in every layouts, are you putting <layout tag? or are you using package-info.java

Comment: yes <layout/> tag is required then it's data Binding class will be  generated. And Package info is configured. It contains the `layoutPrefix`

Comment: Let me try that once

Comment: Sure, waiting for updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add dependency of epoxy:

```
def epoxyVersion = '4.6.3'
implementation "com.airbnb.android:epoxy:$epoxyVersion"
implementation "com.airbnb.android:epoxy-databinding:$epoxyVersion"
kapt "com.airbnb.android:epoxy-processor:$epoxyVersion"
```

After that we need to configure epoxy. In order to do this we need to make a package-info.java file inside the app module and write the below code.

```
@EpoxyDataBindingPattern(rClass = R.class, layoutPrefix = "epoxy_item")
interface Config {
}
```

**Then we need to keep one thing in mind** that whenever we are creating a layout it should be a `data binding layout` and its name should follow the value defined in the `layoutPrefix` variable in `package-info` for example in my case the layoutPrefix is `epoxy_item` so whenever I name a layout it starts with `epoxy_item`.

**Sample Layout: (Layout Name -> epoxy_item_loading)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

  <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<data>

    <variable
        name="isVisible"
        type="Boolean" />


</data>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:isVisible="@{isVisible}">

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:theme="@style/ProgressBlueTheme"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
 </layout>
```

Now to add this layout to epoxy recycler view:

```
        epoxyRecycler.withModels {
               loading {
                id("progress layout")
                isVisible(isLoading)// boolean variable
            }
        }
```

That's all we need to do :)

**NOTE: Sometimes the auto generated classes for the layout is not  generated in android studio, so in that case android studio will show the model as unrecognised and red line below it. In that case you need to rebuild the project.     *sometimes, clean and rebuild project*.}**

Comment: it is data binding, not a view binding

Comment: Hi Francis, how to do view binding ? BTW it makes the development fast so I use this.

Comment: the question is about view binding, not a data binding (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding)

Comment: Francis , I'm asking in context of Epoxy.